# Ubuntu 32bit does not launch from usb

Tags: usb

I have the boot in the correct order, I even select the usb to boot, the bios of my windows 10 pc dissappears for a split second then returns to bios, no error, I've used rubus and unetbootin to create the usb but no luck, I can't find any posts that show these symptoms, I know it works on wintel w8 box as I've seen youtube videos showing it, any help appreciated thanks

Comment: If system is Windows 8 or later from vendor then it is UEFI. And you then need the 64 bit version of Ubuntu to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Then how you select to boot installer is how it installs.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: I thought that to start with, but I've tried the 64bit version too, same issue

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip do you have?

Comment: Sorry, I have a mini pc wintel w8 box, yes, cheap Chinese brand, Intel wm1.0 - 3.1 sound, Intel hd graphics, it's uefi so I'm looking into that but seems there is confliction on how to install, I only have 10gb sd card partition due to tiny size of it, but I saw a video of it working, I managed to install remix os based on lollipop android, so I'm hopeful, I know my question has changed but any suggestions appreciated :)

Comment: If space is an issue, you may want the lighter weight, Xubuntu or Lubuntu flavors. http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours There are a few 32 bit UEFI but 64 bit systems that then need extra effort to install. Is yours 64 bit UEFI?

Comment: It states windows is 32bit and android (wiped some time ago) is 64bit, remix os is 64bit

Comment: Then it sounds like a 64 bit system, but still may depend on how you installed other systems? Often the mixed 32/64 bit systems were Intel Bay Trail chips.

Comment: I installed via boot able usb for windows 10, used uefi boot for remix os after extracting the files from isolated and transfered manually, was wondered if I could use uefi boot program for Linux too

Comment: Best to just create USB flash drive installer. That formats flash drive (erasing it), extracts ISO files to flash drive and makes flash drive bootable. If just UEFI, you can format & extract yourself : UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formated flash & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: I was hoping to do that, can you tell me which file I need to set my bootloader to launch? Linux newbie here :)

Comment: You boot from UEFI, not from Windows mount of flash drive. See first link in first post above.

Comment: But my issue is uefi doesn't load the installer, I see the pen drive, click on it, screen flickers and returns, no matter what pen I use or version, I'll try that version though, thank you for your help, fingers crossed

Comment: Is ubunto 14.04.5 ok? I'm trying to download the versions you stated but it only gives me 14.04.5 or 14.04.1

Comment: I only see 16.04 on this page, You have to search to get to 14.04. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: That's where I searched, found it, clicked it, it gave me 14.04.5, all 3 of them

Comment: Never mind, my mate has got it :)